# Restrict the value that i already exists in database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am adding product details in a form. Before inserting i need to check whether the product name already exists in the database. If exists, have to show a message that it already exists, otherwise the product details should be inserted. I tried to do that by comparing and returning false if exists. But that doesn't work. Can you give me a clue how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 ways of handle that:

1. Select * from table where 'product name' = $this->input->post('productName'). If count(results) > 0 than product exists.
2. Set an unique key in 'product name' db column. Check for db error when you insert new products. This is less precise, because db error can be also caused by another reason, so you should rather use first solution. If that doesn't work, than please provide your code.

Comment: make sure you escape the value if you use method 1, directly concatenating the query in this way could leave you open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: I assumed that he uses Codeigniter active record, where "All values passed to this function are escaped automatically, producing safer queries." http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: alternatively with CI you can do `$this->db->escape($value)` and several other similar functions that do the same thing to different types of data. But as you said, if you use the Active records it will automatically do this for you.